# What is the scope of the injunction "One shall not look at a naked woman"?

Tags: women, sin

It is well known that looking at naked women is sinful according to the Hindu scriptures. The injunction reads like, "One shall not look at a naked woman who isn't his wife."

My question is, what is the full scope of this injunction? Does it include pictures of naked women, drawings, paintings, sculptures, etc.?

If it includes these, then the injunction may actually be, "One shall not look at what appears to be a naked woman."

Comment: there is a difference between 'looking' and 'noticing'. the emphasis in this injunction is on the latter. e.g. one may come across a TV/movie with such women, but there is a split-second decision making process where we decide to either - look away, or look again. the first look is hard to avoid unless you live under a rock, but the second is the sense-control and desire-control (pretty hard to do) that is advised. also, in matters of doubt, try golden-rule. suppose there was a picture of such woman, who might be someone else's wife. would that husband prefer it someone stared at the pic ?

Comment: It definitely seems to mean 'viewing a naked woman'. However it seems to be a unique verse and I have asked a question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34018/alternative-translations-to-manusmriti-4-53

Comment: wherefrom are you getting 'who is not his wife' part?

Comment: A brahmachari should stay away from eight types of sex and thinking about women is one type of it and so the pictures would come under this:)